# How to convert excel PV function to php

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to convert some PV functions from Microsoft Excel to PHP:

```
PV( rate, nper, pmt, FV, Type )
```

It has taken me a long time. Essentially, I need to replicate this functionality into an equivalent PHP function, taking all of the aforementioned arguments. Thanks heaps for the help.

Comment: Take a look at PHPExcel library: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/.

Comment: This is a Mathematics quewstion.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found this really nice function.
$R for the rate, $n number of period, $pmt is the amount paid

> function PV($R,$n,$pmt,$m=1) {
>
> $Z = 1 / (1 + ($R/$m));
>
> return ($pmt * $Z * (1 - pow($Z,$n)))/(1 - $Z);
>
> }

```
echo PV(0,00333333, 180, 1221);
```

Don't forget, if want to know for example how much you will get after 15 years if you pay in 1221€ per month with an annual rate of 4%, you will have to divide per 12 the rate and put 180 months.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [present value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value) and [future value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value) from wikipedia, it gives all the formulas you need.

So you need the two formulas, the present value:

[image: PV Formula]

and the future value formula for simple interest:

[image]

and future value for compond interest

[image]

Now you can write your function.